# Computer works only with 2 monitors

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, freeze

I have a computer with 2 monitors, connected to the single GTS 250 video card. One with DVI and one with HDMI. Once I unplug one of these monitors, my screen goes black and in few additional seconds, my PC freezes.

Here's what I tried:

1. Reinstall Windows 10
2. Install different versions of NVidia driver
3. Plug the single monitor to VGA

And they did not work.

But what worked was:

1. Use Ubuntu 16.04
2. Use low-resolution mode (F3)

My configuration:

CPU: Intel Core i7 950 @ 3.07GHz

VGA: NVIDIA Geforce GTS 250

---

A minute before each freeze I have this warning:

> Display driver nvlddmkm stopped responding and has successfully
>   recovered.

---

What could be the reason of this issue and how do I make my PC work with single monitor?

Comment: Anything in the log files? (eventvwr.msc).

Comment: @Hennes 102 errors last hour. 3 critical. But critical because I had to hard reset my PC three times.